# Get image size in pixels using opencv2-python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I need the width and height of the image `in pixels` using opencv2(python)

I tried using `im.shape` but I dont think it gives the output in pixel units.

I measured the pixel units using `page ruler` extension and somehow it doesnt match with `im.shape` output.

Can anyone please tell me the units of im.shape and how to convert it into pixels?

Comment: The unit **IS** the pixel. How much it's big depends on your screen

Comment: But if its pixel why is not matching with the measurements I got using page ruler extension?

Comment: Its approximately double the pixel values.

Comment: Can you tell me why a 1920x1080 (full hd) image is large something like 5 cm on a smartphone, and something like 1 meter on a tv?

Comment: But I am using the same screen while using the extension and to measure it using openv.I am sorry if I am missing something obvious but I still don't get it!

Comment: maybe you're doing something wrong. I get correct dimensions from page ruler and I can assure you that im.shape gives you an image's dimensions correctly and in pixels...
provide your code and the picture

Answer (score 0):

you could use Pillow library as following:

```
from PIL import Image

print(Image.open(args["image"]).size)
```

Hope it helps to someone!